# Can't POST a collection

Tags: spring-data-rest

I have a simple Entity with a single collection mapped.

```
@Entity
public class Appointment Identifiable<Integer>   {  

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="TRAK_NBR")
    private String trackNumber;

    @OneToMany(fetch =FetchType.EAGER, cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="CNSM_APT_VER_WRK_I", nullable = false)
    private Set<Product> products = new HashSet<Product>();
}

@Entity
public class Product implements Identifiable<Integer> {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "CNSM_PRD_VER_WRK_I")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "PRD_MDL_NBR")
    private String model;

    @Column(name = "PRD_SPEC_DSC")
    private String description;
}
```

In my application when I only include a PagingAndSortingRepository for Appointment.  I can call the POST command with the following payload.

```
{
  "trackNumber" : "XYZ123",
  "products": [
    {"model" : "MODEL",
     "description" : "NAME"
    }]
}
```

When I add a PagingAndSortingRepository for Product and try the same POST I get the following error message.

```
{
  "cause" : {
    "cause" : {
      "cause" : null,
      "message" : null
    },
    "message" : "(was java.lang.NullPointerException) (through reference chain: com..model.Appointment[\"products\"])"
  },
  "message" : "Could not read JSON: (was java.lang.NullPointerException) (through reference chain: com.model.Appointment[\"products\"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: (was java.lang.NullPointerException) (through reference chain: com.model.AppointmentVerification[\"products\"])"
}

My GET payload with both Repositories returns this.  This is my desired format.  The link to products should be included

{
  "trackNumber" : "XYZ123", 
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/consumerappointment/appointments/70"
    },
    "products" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/consumerappointment/appointments/70/products"
  }
}
```

With only the Appointment repository I get the following payload and can post the list of products.

```
{
  "trackNumber" : "XYZ123",
  "products" : [ {
    "model" : "MODEL",
    "description" : "NAME",
  } ],
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/consumerappointment/appointments/1"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Let's take a step back and make sure you understand what's happening here: if a repository is detected, Spring Data REST exposes a [dedicated set of resources](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/repository-resources.html) for it to manage the aggregates handled by the repository via HTTP. Thus, if you have repositories for multiple entities related to each other, the relationship is represented as a link. This is why you see the products inlined with only the `AppointmentRepository` in place and the `products` link in place once you create a `ProductRepository`.

If you want to expose both repositories as resources, you need to hand the URIs of the `Product` instances in the payload for the `POST` to create an `Appointment`. That means, instead of posting this:

```
{ "trackNumber" : "XYZ123",
  "products": [
    { "model" : "MODEL",
      "description" : "NAME"
    }
  ]
}
```

you'd create a `Product` first:

```
POST /products
{ "model" : "MODEL",
  "description" : "NAME" }

201 Created
Location: …/products/4711
```

And then hand the ID of the product to the `Appointment` payload:

```
{ "trackNumber" : "XYZ123",
  "products": [ "…/products/4711" ]}
```

In case you don't want any of this (no resources exposed for `Product` in the first place, use `@RepositoryRestResource(exported = false)` on `PersonRepository`. That would still leave you with the bean instance created for the repo, but no resources exported and the resource exposed for `Appointment`s back to inlining related `Product`s.

Comment: I see, that's not obvious from the code up there. I am of course not into the details of your database design but a foreign key, doesn't mean it has to be set in the first place. It could just be the reference that ties the product to an appointment later on (hence your `Set`). That said, I tried to explain why it works as it works. Totally possible that the model doesn't match your use case but you can't have to separate aggregate roots that have a bidirectional relationship between each other by definition.

Comment: My product table has a foreign key constraint back to the appointment table.  So creating products first doesn't work.  Can I over ride the behavior of the POST when I have both repositories?  I need to be able to create the appointment and products in the same transaction but still have the link to the products in the GET.

Comment: Yes, just providing a manually implemented controller for the appropriate path and HTTP method should do the trick. Still, I think that's masking a fundamental design problem.

Comment: I created a small application with a manually implemented controller that we talked about.  I'm still not able to post the full payload like I was thinking I could.  Seems like I'm having the same issue as this https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-377.  My sample code can be found at https://github.com/zachariahyoung/posterror.