# How to handle multiple REST calls when process single message

Tags: rest, spring-integration

I have created a REST API, which is being called from a Spring Integration application.  Currently messages are coming into the SI application with the following payload.

```
{
  "trackNumber" : "XYZ123",
  "products": [
    {"model" : "MODEL",
     "description" : "NAME"
    }]
}
```

The current REST API can handle this payload as a single POST using the following configuration.

```
<int:chain id="chain" input-channel="addChannel">               
        <int:header-enricher >
            <int:header name="content-type" value="application/json"></int:header>  
        </int:header-enricher>
        <int-http:outbound-gateway id="appointment"
            url="http://test.com/appointments/"
            http-method="POST"
            expected-response-type="java.lang.String"
            charset="UTF-8"/>       
    </int:chain>
```

Now what I'm wondering is how to process the messages by calling a POST to create the entity with only the track number.

Then make another POST call for each of the products.

Once I break out the separate calls, the http outbound-gateway will not work any more because it doesn't pass the complete message so I can't make another call for creating the products.

The other thing I'm having issues with is handling a failure.  For example if a product doesn't save and fails, then how would I best handle the reprocessing of the original message?

Also reference my other question where I talk about using spring data rest.

[Can't POST a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24356680/cant-post-a-collection)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you need to send one request for the `trackNumber` only, and if it is `200 OK`, process each item from `products` one by one.

I'd say it should be like this:

```
<int:chain input-channel="sendChannel">
    <int:header-enricher >
        <int:header name="content-type" value="application/json"/>
        <int:header name="originalPayload" expression="payload"/>
    </int:header-enricher>
    <int:transformer expression="#jsonPath(payload, '$.trackNumber')"/>
    <int-http:outbound-gateway url="http://test.com/appointments/"
                      http-method="POST"
                      expected-response-type="java.lang.String"
                      charset="UTF-8">
        <int-http:request-handler-advice-chain>
            <int:retry-advice/>
        </int-http:request-handler-advice-chain>
    </outbound-gateway>
    <int:splitter expression="#jsonPath(headers.originalPayload, '$.products')"/>
    <int:object-to-json-transformer/>
    <int-http:outbound-gateway url="http://test.com/appointments/"
                      http-method="POST"
                      expected-response-type="java.lang.String"
                      charset="UTF-8"/>
</int:chain>
```

Of course, you should polishing it according to your requirements and may be build new JSON just for the `trackNumber` value.

With this config:

1. The inbound `payload` is stored in the `headers` for future reuse.
2. `#jsonPath` SpEL-function comes to the rescue to extract some part of entire JSON
3. The first `<int-http:outbound-gateway>` sends request just for the `trackNumber`
4. `<int:retry-advice/>` provides an `retry` ability for the HTTP endpoint in case of failure.
5. `<int:splitter>` with `#jsonPath` populates messages for each `product`
6. `<int:object-to-json-transformer/>` converts a `Map` for `product` to the JSON
7. The second `<int-http:outbound-gateway>` sends requests for each `product`.

Comment: Will the http response headers be mapped to into the SI message on the reply-channel?  The first POST will return a Location url in the response and I will need that for the second http outbound gateway.

Comment: Also is it a good practice to put payloads inside the header?  If this was a JMS message not sure I would.

Comment: It's not a problem for an internal Spring Integration usage. Headers are just object. So, you can store there anything you want. Of course, when you decide to send message to an external system you should `filter` such headers, or framework will do it for you, e.g. `JdbcMessageStore`